# Custom style for all Qt Quick Button Control states

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm looking for a way to create custom styles for all states of a button with QML. So far I have only found the following way to create a style that can be applied to multiple buttons

```
Component {
  id: leftButtonStyle

  ButtonStyle {

      background: Rectangle {
          width: control.width
          height: control.height
          color: "black"
      }

      label: Text {
          font.family: "Helvetica"
          font.pointSize: 10
          color: "#949599"
          text: control.text
      }
  }

}

Button {
    text:"Button One"
    style: leftButtonStyle
}

Button {
        text:"Button Two"
        style: leftButtonStyle
}
```

But this only changes the normal state of the button, and can not find a way to give a style when the botton is pressed.

Comment: Implementation issues belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: @GlenH7 So, how can I move it? I think I do not have privileges for that.

Comment: You can flag the question and request a moderator to migrate.  I have voted to migrate as well, but there's only one vote on it at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `ButtonStyle`, you can use `control.hovered` and `control.pressed` to determine, when button is being hovered or pressed.

```
  ButtonStyle {
     background: Rectangle {
        width: control.width
        height: control.height
        color: control.pressed ? "gray" : "black"
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I'm starting to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the example project named *QtQuick Control Touch Gallery* or you can see here for online version http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-touch-content-buttonpage-qml.html